# OpenCV with XCode GUI and c++

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

Is it possible, using only c++ to design an opencv GUI using XCode's Cocoa Framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this c++ library [wxwidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org). Add the path to xcode and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, I will try as soon as I can.

Comment: Unfortunately, in order to use wxwidgets in GUI , i have to use Cocoa application. Therefore I have to use Qt

Comment: qt is perhaps the best available for c++ though I have only tried QT with QTCreator not xcode.